# Can I keep an image as the face of a cube?

Tags: three.js, cube

Instead of using

```
    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( 0x00ff80 );
```

to set the color , can I keep and image as the face?

Answer (score 0):

well you can apply a [texture](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_compressed) on the face that you want color

**Update after James Donnelly comment**

You can use a texture, load the image then create a material to render the cube

```
var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./images/mylogo.jpg");
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map: map
        })));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.